# vba range("A1").value gives gives #Value! When entered in a function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-udf

I want it return multiple values from a VBA function called from an Excel spreadsheet but always get the error #Value!

One example found on the web:

```
Sub ReturnCellValue()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 3.14159
End Function
```

This Function returns #Value!

```
Function ReturnCellValue()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 3.14159
End Function
```

This single line of code works in the immediate  winnow.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 3.14159
```

All of the examples I have found have been sub.  How do you call a sub from a function?

Comment: None of the code you posted works. You cannot use `Sub` with `End Function` (it should be `End Sub`) and a `Sub` does not return a value (`Sub` is equivalent to `void` in C-style languages).

Comment: A UDF can't have side-effects. Writing to the worksheet is a side-effect. Functions *return* a value.

Answer (score 2):

This function:

```
Function ReturnCellValue()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 3.14159
End Function
```

- Does not return a cell's value, instead it sets a cell's value (and VBA's `=` operator forms a statement, not an expression, so you cannot nest assignment).
- Does not return *any* value because you're not returning a value (return a value in a VBA function by assigning-to the function's name).

You probably want this:

```
Function ReturnCellValue() As Variant
    ReturnCellValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
End Function
```